# How to show the Value associated with the slicer using ISFILTERED() in Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 3 slicers Year, Month, and Category from different tables joining to main table. Image below

The Year comes from the Year table, Month from the month table, category from the category table, they are used as slicers and joined to main table named pbi image below

[image]

If there is no data associated with the category then I want to display 100

Here is the Measure Code:

```
ACTprod = 
IF ( ISFILTERED('Yr'[Year]) && ISFILTERED('Mon'[Month]) && 
    ISFILTERED('Category'[Cat]),
    if(HASONEVALUE(pbi[avail]), LASTNONBLANK(pbi[avail],""), 100),
    "Select Year, Month& Category"
   )
```

Here is my Data:

[image]

when I filter 2021, 2, and oracle, I get 100 which is not true, it should be 99.97

when I filter 2021, 3, and oracle, I get 99.39 which is not true, it should display 100

Can someone explain why it doesn't work? and how to make it work?

Comment: I copied your data table and measure and for me it seems to work as you want it to. Selecting 2021, Feb, Oracle I get 99,97768 and then selecting March I get 100. Can you provide your model?

Comment: Hi @OscarLar, Yes you were right, there was a wrong connection in the model, I had 16 views tied up in the model, I fixed it. It works fine now. Do you know how to close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function works fine, there was an error in a relationship that joins the views.

Make sure the filter is set in single and not both.